# TinyMCE Readonly Body

Tags: tinymce, contenteditable, readonly

I am using TinyMCE editor for my application.

I want to have my body and the presentation toolbar on screen with "readonly".

```
readonly:true
```

makes the presentation bar disable which is not acceptable by client (needs both content area and toolbar).

I successully made the:

```
body.contentEditable = false;
```

which works good but when i click any of the presentation icon or button it gives the effect like when i click bold it makes the document text bold which should not.

Comment: can you show it in [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/)

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/40caab

Comment: please try to add bullets and some alignment, as my requirement it should not take effect even after clicking on it.
Thanks...

Comment: so, what you want is to have a visible toolbar, which is not functional?

Comment: i have added a demo in the answer below.... check out if it meets your requirement

Comment: Did you try it with firefox?, don´t works and its driving me mad

Comment: please refer this [demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/T0caab).
it works well in all browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the following to undo the changes in the editor and execute it onchange_callback.

```
//undo all the changes in the editor    
tinyMCE.activeEditor.undoManager.undo();

//remove all undo levels so there will no possibility of redoing last action
tinyMCE.activeEditor.undoManager.clear();
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/40caab/2)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot that also a good way but I found something different with CSS please have a look on fiddle for more...

I have applied the disable class to the toolbar ID.

document.getElementById("elm1_toolbargroup").setAttribute("Class","mceButtonDisabled");